# MySQL stores the common special characters, but not the rare ones

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

When I try to insert some rare special characters (∨ ∧ → ↔ ∴), they get stored as question marks. But when I try to insert some more common special characters (© ® ¬ á) everything goes fine.

I've set every variable, database, table and connection I could find to UTF-8, but no luck yet. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Here is a minimal example:

```
<?php
header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8;');

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test', $connection);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');

$special_character = '∴';

echo 'Encoding of the special character before insert: '.base64_encode($special_character).'<br />';

mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ("'.$special_character.'")');

$query = mysql_query('SELECT column FROM table');
while ($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    echo 'Encoding of the special character after retrieval: '.base64_encode($ROW['column']).'<br />';
    echo 'Output: '.$ROW['column'].'<br />';
    }

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

The output of this script is:

> Encoding of the special character before insert: 4oi0
>
> Encoding of the special character after retrieval: Pw==
>
> Output: ?

Could it be because I have the standard MySQL installation for Mac OSX, which doesn't have a my.cnf file? Maybe the defaults that come with this installation are not UTF-8? Anyone knows?

UPDATE: I have determined that the problem is in my local installation of MySQL, because it does not appear when I run the code in my web host. I still want to solve it though.

Comment: Are they truly stored as questions marks or is phpmyadmin/browser displaying them that way?

Comment: Font issue? What font are you using to output the characters? How are you inputting them?

Comment: I tried inputing both via PHP, and via Terminal, and I tried displaying them both ways too. Still see the question marks.

Comment: The font is Helvetica, and if I write the characters as html entities, they display fine, so its probably not a font issue.

Comment: insert ∴ into your db. Now, you need to provide us with [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/base64_encode)() output before inserting into db, and after retrieving. Same script. I bet it's the same 3 byte character in both cases, which means you need to send proper http header to tell browser its utf-8(no, a meta html tag doesnt cut it).

Comment: @chris before the insert, the output of base64_encode() was "4oi0", the same as after the insert and retrival... does that mean something to you?

Comment: looks good. The problem is not anything to do with your database. you just need to convince the browser you have sent utf-8. `header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @chris I correct myself: the encoding is NOT the same before the insert and after. Before it is "4oi0" but after it is "Pw==", the encoding of the question mark, I presume. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: in that case maybe its best you post a minimal, but complete script which demonstrates it.

Comment: verify. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'` Also, it really shouldn't matter, but use `$connection` for `mysql_query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was in my local installation of MySQL. I was using an outdated version that came bundled with my Mac OSX 10.5. I downloaded and installed the more recent version of MySQL, and problem solved.

And that's why, boys and girls, it is always good to have the most recent version of the software you use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the eclipse java console in the past. The information in the database in my case was stored properly. What happened is that the console is not meant to display those characters.

To see them I had my application generate a file with the special characters in them and opened them in notepad++ with which you can change the character set to apply to the file. I had this issue with Russian characters.

Answer (score 0):

What you storage in database it must content in charset table that you use
for example for UTF-8:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: You should provide an example or 2 for what you mean the UTF-8 may be used but not displayed, etc...

Comment: If you meant to say that I must convert the charset of the table to UTF-8, I've done it already.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one. Your connection to mysql also has to be set to UTF8. After initially connecting to mysql, your first "query" should be "SET NAMES UTF8". If you are using a terminal program, run that "query" also.

Comment: I just tried adding it, but it makes no difference (updated the example). Also, I read somewhere that the function mysql_set_charset() does what SET NAMES does, among other things.